# Backbone Body element View not Rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, render, el

I'm having some issues with Backbone View rendering. Could anyone point at my mistake?

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<strong><%= title %></strong> - <%= author %>'),
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'cover',
    id: '',
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('View initialized');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var instance = new Book({
    title: 'Thinking, Fast and Slow',
    author: 'Daniel Kahneman',
    issued: '2011'
});
console.log(instance.get('title') + ' by ' + instance.get('author') + ' added to catalogue');

var something = new BookView({model: instance, el: $('body')});
something.render();
```

The thing is that I'm reading documentation as well as Backbone Fundamentals book and not getting why after `el: $('body')` View is not appended to body tag.

At the same time `$('body').append(something.el);` from console works perfectly, but doesn't make me feel that I understand framework concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend briefly on what @TJ has mentioned, it's worthwhile noting that there is difference between `el` and `$el`.

[**`$el`**](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) is a cached jQuery (or Zepto) reference to the view's element: (Since [v0.9.0](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/018c19a12aff863106f86397f3a7c229b025f506))

> A cached jQuery object for the view's element. A handy reference
>   instead of re-wrapping the DOM element all the time.

[**`this.el`**](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element:

> `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element;
>   otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id`
>   and [`attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes) properties. If none are set, `this.el` is an empty `div`

---

**To get you current code working**, all you need to do is remove the `tagName`, `id` and `className` properties:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<strong><%= title %></strong> - <%= author %>'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Since you are calling `render()` from  `initialize`, you don't need to call it again after it has been initialized:

```
var something = new BookView({model: instance, el: $('body')});
```

---

Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t29bvcdb/) with your working code

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `el` property along with other properties like `tagName`.

`el` property is used to to point to an existing element in DOM to which the view is associated.

So if you pass `el: $('body')` in options but then specify `tagName: 'div'` in view, obviously it doesn't make sense.

So if you want backbone to create a new element for the view, use properties such as  `tagName` , `className` , `id`. You should then manually append this view pointing to newly created element to DOM.

Else use `el` property to point to an element that already exists in DOM.